# What sourcebooks do I need for information on the United Netherlands?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I have a campaign idea that will be taking shadowrunners around the United Netherlands, but information on the region seems to be incredibly scarce.

I have managed to find [this page](http://denver.wikidot.com/info:the-united-netherlands) that seems to have taken some snippets from sourcebooks and formed them into a quick overview, but it doesn't include any source information, so I am not even certain if their information is accurate.

After searching some forums, I found a mention to 'Shadows of Europe', a third edition sourcebook, but I have no idea if the information in that book is still even relevant to the fifth edition as the timeline has progressed quite a bit.

Are there any more recent sourcebooks that deal with the United Netherlands?

Comment: Going by the front page of that website I suspect that this is taken from a fan-made campaign and is not part of the offical setting. Are you certain this is 100% official stuff you're looking at?

Comment: I am not. Hence the question if there is any official sourcebooks for newer versions of shadowrun. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Page(shadowhelix)](http://shadowhelix.pegasus.de/UNL) lists some sources. Some are german, some are english.
(There ist also a [english wiki](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/United_Netherlands) with less information)

I also found [this](http://www.dystopic.de/files/lote_RC3.pdf) fanmade german pdf with a rather impressive overhaul on the UNL for the 60s. It might give you some inspiration to fill some gaps.

Some sources are found only in german as the german publisher(Pegasus) adds much content specific for the ADL as a bonus.

Comment: Sadly enough, while I did take German in high school, it is no longer truly up to par. Do you know if there were ever any English translations made?

Comment: The first link lists its sources in german and english. The english books might help, but i can't guarantee it, as i don't own any books pre Edition 5. I also added an link to a english wiki, but here aren't that much information. I assume the pdf was never translated as its creation alone took 3 years and was fanmade.